# Setup Redis Sentinel with Multiple Hosts

Tags: laravel, redis, redis-sentinel

I'm trying to connect my app to a redis sentinel but I noticed that it is possible to have multiple hosts for your sentinels. Does it mean that my app is connected to multiple sentinels or will it use the next host in case the first host is unavailable?

https://github.com/monospice/laravel-redis-sentinel-drivers#specifying-multiple-hosts

> **Specifying Multiple Hosts**
>
> To supply multiple hosts for a connection
>   through environment variables, set the value of any `*_HOST` variable to
>   a comma-seperated string of hostnames or IP addresses:
>
> ```
> REDIS_HOST=sentinel1.example.com, sentinel2.example.com, ...
> REDIS_CACHE_HOST=10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3
> REDIS_QUEUE_HOST=tcp://10.0.0.4:26379, tcp://10.0.0.4:26380, ...
> ```